# Are all planes painted white first?

Tags: airplane, paint

Is white used as base paint before other colors? So is the paint on coloured parts thicker than in white parts?

Answer (score 1):

Not always.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cg8-O1FcsrI) (screenshot below) shows an ex-US-Airways A319 being redecorated in the American fashion.  While the blue and red paint for the tail detailing is indeed applied on top of a white undercoat, the blue and red paint for the detailing on the mid-to-forward fuselage is applied directly on top of the yellow primer coat, with no white undercoat; the coat of white paint on these parts of the fuselage goes *on top of* the other colors.

[image: this plane gets painted white last]

That said, some browsing through airliner-painting videos gives the impression that, although a white undercoat isn't *universal*, it does seem to be surprisingly common, even for liveries that otherwise have little or no white.